# Várias consultas com uma única conexão

Tags: php, query, mysqli

Estou fazendo um site onde na mesma página preciso fazer várias consultas, no mysqli.

quando executo o site no xampp roda perfeito. porem no servidor da web não.
Apenas vem a primeira consulta e não da erro nem um.

é como se eu não desse um `sql->close()` segue uma exemplificação

```
$conecta = new mysqli($host, $login, $senha, $banco) or print (mysql_error());


if ($sql = $conecta->prepare("Call SP_proc(?)"))
{
    $Ind_TrabAcao = "T";
    // Atribui valores às variáveis da chamada
    $sql->bind_param("s", $Ind_TrabAcao);
  // Executa a consulta
  $sql->execute();
  // Atribui o resultado encontrado a variáveis
  $sql->bind_result($id_trabalhos_acoes, $Nom_TrabalhoAcoe, $Nom_ImgCapa);
  // Para cada resultado encontrado...
  $contador = 0;
  while ($sql->fetch()) 
  {
    $contador++;


    ...


        }
  } // fim while
  // Fecha a consulta
  $sql->close();
}
```

...

```
if ($sql = $conecta->prepare("Call SP_proc(?)")) 
{
    $Ind_TrabAcao = "A";
    // Atribui valores às variáveis da chamada
    $sql->bind_param("s", $Ind_TrabAcao);
  // Executa a consulta
  $sql->execute();
  // Atribui o resultado encontrado a variáveis
  $sql->bind_result($id_trabalhos_acoes, $Nom_TrabalhoAcoe, $Nom_ImgCapa);
  // Para cada resultado encontrado...
  $contador = 0;
  while ($sql->fetch()) 
  {
    $contador++;


    ...


        }
  } // fim while
  // Fecha a consulta
  $sql->close();
}
```

o que devo fazer?

Comment: Você colocou o código duas vezes, isto quer dizer que você realmente está o executando duas vezes, como está na pergunta? Não consegui entender.

Comment: No host de produçã, no ínicio do arquivo adicione essas duas linhas e veja se aparece algum erro: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Na linha da conexão tome CUIDADO, o certo é usar o `mysqli_error($conexao);` e não `mysql_error();`